# Failing to create an asset on Trappist parachain

Tags: test-network, local, trappist

I cloned the trappist repo, and I successfully run `cargo build --release`.

After running `./target/release/trappist-node --dev` I tried to create an asset by using the `create` extrinsic placed inside the `assets` pallet.

This resulted in the following error: `trappist 1010: invalid transaction: transaction call is not expected`

I tried executing other extrinsics(e.g. `system.remark`) and that was successful.
I am not sure I understand why this is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Trappist we have implemented a custom lockdown mode pallet to pause al the transactions in case is needed. Soon, this pallet will be replaced by the pallets being worked here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12092

For being able to commit transactions to Trappist just disable the lockdown mode by calling the extrinsic `lockdownMode.deactivateLockdownMode()` from the sudo tab this requires a privileged origin to be executed).

Anyway i will update the Trappist documentation to let the users to know how to disable this lockdown mode or maybe changing the GenesisConfig for the local setup so it starts with the lockdown mode deactivated.